# Cannot find x path from request in wiremock

Tags: scala, xpath, wiremock

I'm trying to create stub in wirkmock. But it's show 'request not match' when I hit the endpoint

it's work when I use a simple check

**In code**:

```scala
  stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/v1/test.svc"))
    .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/xml"))
      .withRequestBody(containing("<b:Name>Test</b:Name>"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
      .withStatus(200)
      .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
      .withBody("Passed")));
```

**Request**:

endpoint

```
http://{{url}}/v1/test.svc
```

header

```
Content-Type:application/xml
```

body

```xml
<test xmlns="http://abc.example.com">
    <request xmlns:b="http://abc.example.com/b" xmlns:i="http://abc.example.com/i">
        <b:Name>Test</b:Name>
        <b:Age>18</b:Age>
        <b:Count>2020</b:Count>
    </request>
</test>
```

**Result**:

```
Passed
```

But it's not working when I try to use xpath for check some values

**In code**:

```scala
  stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/paymentapi/paymentservice.svc"))
    .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/xml"))
      .withRequestBody(containing("<b:Name>Test</b:Name>"))
      .withRequestBody(matchingXPath("//Age/text()",equalTo("18")))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
      .withStatus(200)
      .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
      .withBody("Passed")));
```

**Result**:

```
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/vi/test.svc                                               | /v1/test.svc
                                                           |
Content-Type: application/xml                              | Content-Type: application/xml
                                                           |
//Age/text()                                               | <test xmlns="http://abc.example.com">
    <request  <<<<< Body does not match
                                                           | xmlns:b="http://abc.example.com/b"
                                                           | xmlns:i="http://abc.example.com/i">
<b:Name>Test</b:Name>
        <b:Age>18</b:Age>
<b:Count>2020</b:Count>
    </request>
</test>
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone tell me how to check value for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Age` element is under the `http://abc.example.com/b` namespace URI. From [Wiremock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) you can declare the in scope namespace for your XPath expression like this:

```
.withRequestBody(matchingXPath("//b:Age[.=18]")
  .withXPathNamespace("b", "http://abc.example.com/b"))
```

Comment: Many thanks!! it work for me. I dont understand when I read a wiremock document on that time